# how do I link a subform to a list in main form vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a subform that I want to link  to a list on main form, and If I change the value in list, then the content of subform should be changed to, how can I do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLick on your subform frame and use the link properties:

[image: Subform Data Properties]

The `Link Master Fields` should be your listbox, and the `Link Child Fields` should be its corresponding foreign key field in the subform.